# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when trying to unpack dict in python for data labeling with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I created a dictionary that label each api endpoint from my backend to a product group.
Currently I'm trying in python 3.7.6 to use this dictionary to further label all data in the csv that I get from NewRelic with data from all transactions (avg latency, request count, etc.).
The code is teh following:

```
response = requests.request(
        "GET", self.url,
        auth=(self.user, self.password)
    )
    with open(
            "data.csv",
            "w",
            encoding='utf8'
    ) as jfp:
        jfp.write(response.text)
    doc = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(self.path, sep=";"))
    doc_dic = pd.Series(doc.ProductGroup.values, index=doc.Action).to_dict()
    resp = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=","))
    for k, v in doc_dic:
        if k == resp.Action:
            resp.insert(0, "Product Group", v)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Project/Dev/analytics/app/data.py", line 53, in <module>
    Data().csv_data()
  File "C:/Project/Dev/analytics/app/data.py", line 42, in csv_data
    for k, v in obj:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

In the dict obj, the keys are the api endpoint and the values are the product groups where each api endpoint belongs to.
The expected behaviour is, after comparing the dictionary with the csv file returned as response from the request, pandas inserting a column with the proper product group for each endpoint (index 0 for product group and index 1 for endpoints).
What can I do to get this output?

Comment: try `doc_dic.items()` in for loop

Comment: Looks like the csv file is malformed - meaning, some lines only have a single column, i.e. `key` and no `value`. You could use a defaultdict if you have a default missing value -
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code:

```
for k, v in doc_dic:
        if k == resp.Action:
            resp.insert(0, "Product Group", v)
```

with:

```
for k, v in doc_dic.items():
        if k == resp.Action:
            resp.insert(0, "Product Group", v)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine. I just have another error now, but I think it is because the csv has some endpoint that are not labeled inside the dict (ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()).

Answer (score 2):

You need to do: `for k, v in  doc_dic.items()`